# Why do I get a timeout error in Sinch?

Tags: sinch

I am trying to implement a video chat on my website. The user handling is done by my backend which creates a "signedUserTicket" and that ticket is then used to start the sinchClient. However when I try starting a call just after the message

> Successfully initiated call, waiting for MXP signalling.

I get an error saying

> Call PROGRESSING timeout. Will hangup call.

Also I get a Chrome warning saying

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

(But I don't think this is the reason for the timeout.)

So after checking in the network tab to find out whether the requests are correctly sent I realized that the problem is always with the requests going to `https://rebtelsdk.pubnub.com`. For example the request to `https://rebtelsdk.pubnub.com/subscribe/sub-c-56224c36-d446-11e3-a531-02ee2ddab7fe/f590205a-c82d-4ec1-bd72-f2997097cbedS/0/14932956939626496?uuid=3b47f938-609d-4940-bb0e-bd7030cb3697&pnsdk=PubNub-JS-Web%2F3.7.2` takes about 20 seconds and it seems to cancel the requests after about 10 seconds giving me the timeout error.

Any ideas on how to fix this?